# Problem controlling weight and style of math fonts

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-fonts

I'm trying to use typographical conventions to distinguish between several different types of mathematical entities. The C in the default math font looks very close to the C in `\mathcal`. My first thought was to use sans-serif, but the results look ugly. I tried using `\mathscr` from mathrsfs, but `$\mathscr C$` and `$\bm{\mathscr{C}}$` look almost identical. Requiring xelatex is not an option, but I can use euler instead of mathrsfs if that would help, as long a E and C are readily distinguishable from their rendition in the default math font and as long as normal weight script is readily distinguishable from bold script.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 

\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\showlabels{cite}
\showlabels{cref}
\showlabels{crefrange}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfbd}{T1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{\itdefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfbd}{bold}{T1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{\itdefault}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfbdit}{T1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{\itdefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfbdit}{bold}{T1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{\itdefault}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{T1}{\sfdefault}{}{\itdefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{normal}{T1}{\sfdefault}{}{\itdefault}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfsl}{T1}{\sfdefault}{}{\sldefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfsl}{normal}{T1}{\sfdefault}{}{\sldefault}

\begin{document}

 $C$ default

 $\mathit C$ mathit

 $\mathcal C$ mathcal

 $\mathscr C$ mathscr

 $\mathsf{C}$ mathsf

$\mathsfbd{C}$ mathsfbd

$\mathsfbdit{C}$ mathsfbdit

$\mathsfit{C}$ mathsfit

$\mathsfsl{C}$ mathsfsl

 $\bm C$ bm default

 $\bm{\mathcal{C}}$ bm mathcal

 $\bm{\mathscr{C}}$ bm mathscr

 $\bm{\mathit{\mathsf{C}}}$ bm mathit mathsf

$\bm{\mathsf{C}}$ bm mathsf

$\bm{\mathsfbdit{C}}$ bm mathsfbdit

$\bm{\mathsfbd{C}}$ bm mathsfbd

$\bm{\mathsfit{C}}$ bm mathsfit

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no bold version for `\mathscr`, so `\mathscr{C}` and `\bm{\mathscr{C}}` don't look very close, they are the same.

Answer (score 4):

You could try stix, that has a wide range of alphabets:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}

$
C+
\mathit{C}+
\mathcal{C}+
\mathscr{C}+
\mathrm{C}+
\mathsf{C}+
\mathfrak{C}+
\mathbfscr{C}+
\mathbfit{C}
$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't stix require xetex or the equivalent? I have to be able to submit to organizations that compile using pdflatex.

Comment: @shmuel the above image was generated via pdftex from the posted code

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to define several of the fonts you have. For the script font you can use STIX.

By the way, no argument to `\DeclareMathAlphabet` or `\SetMathAlphabet` should be empty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{T1}{\sfdefault}{m}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{bold}{T1}{\sfdefault}{bx}{sl}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{LS1}{stixscr}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{bold}{LS1}{stixscr}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

$CE$ default

$\bm{C}\bm{E}$ default bold

$\mathit{C}\mathit{E}$ mathit

$\bm{\mathit{C}}\bm{\mathit{E}}$ mathit bold

$\mathcal{C}\mathcal{E}$ mathcal

$\bm{\mathcal{C}}\bm{\mathcal{E}}$ mathcal bold

$\mathscr{C}\mathscr{E}$ mathscr

$\bm{\mathscr{C}}\bm{\mathscr{E}}$ mathscr bold

$\mathsf{C}\mathsf{C}$ mathsf

$\bm{\mathsf{C}}\bm{\mathsf{E}}$ mathsf bold

$\mathsfit{C}\mathsfit{E}$ mathsfit

$\bm{\mathsfit{C}}\bm{\mathsfit{E}}$ mathsfit bold

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to type `\bm` each time, just define

```
\newcommand{\mathsfbdit}[1]{\bm{\mathsfit{#1}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't stix require xetex or the equivalent? What is the parameter to `\DeclareMathAlphabet` and `\SetMathAlphabet` for normal weight?

Comment: @shmuel No, the STIX fonts are also available for `pdflatex`, as you can see by testing the example. Normal weight is `m` (or `\mddefault`).

Comment: I just tried stix with my main docuent and got "! LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.". I removed amssymb but still got "! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal." Using the [notext] option lso didn't help. Works fine with XeTeX, but I have to send the file to places that use pdfLaTeX.

Comment: When I use stix in my real document I get error messages from pdfLaTeX, e.g. `! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.`, although I can compile with XeLaTeX. I tried using `\usepackage{stix}[notext,not1]`, but that doesn't change anything. If I move stix before amsmath, as the stix documentation recommends, then I get `! LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.`even with XeTeX.

Comment: @shmuel That may happen with all the declarations you seem to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that while stix won't work, stix2 will:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}[notext,not1]
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\showlabels{cite}
\showlabels{cref}
\showlabels{crefrange}

\begin{document}

$E C$ default

$\mathbb{E C}$ mathbb

$\mathbf{E C}$ mathbf

$\mathcal{E C}$ mathcal

$\mathfrak{E C}$ mathfrak

$\mathit{E C}$ mathit

$\mathrm{E C}$ mathrm

$\mathscr{E C}$ mathscr

$\bm{E C}$ bm default

$\bm{\mathbb{E C}}$ bm mathbb

$\bm{\mathbf{E C}}$ bm mathbf

$\bm{\mathfrak{E C}}$ bm mathfrak

$\bm{\mathit{E C}}$ bm mathit

$\bm{\mathrm{E C}}$ bm mathrm

$\bm{\mathscr{E C}}$ bm mathscr

$\bm{\mathsf{E C}}$ bm mathsf

$\pmb{E C}$ pmb default

$\pmb{\mathbb{E C}}$ pmb mathbb

$\pmb{\mathbf{E C}}$ pmb mathbf

$\pmb{\mathcal{E C}}$ pmb mathcal

$\pmb{\mathfrak{E C}}$ pmb mathfrak

$\pmb{\mathscr{E C}}$ pmb mathscr

$\cdot$ cdot

$\circ$ circ

$\odot$ odot

$\mathbin{\cdot}$ mathbin cdot

$\mathbin{\circ}$ mathbin circ

$\mathbin{\odot}$ mathbin odot

\end{document}
```

BTW, although the stix documentation says to put stix before amsmath, that generates an error message; with stix2, the documented placement works fine.